# Display XML Content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing

I am a beginner with programming and with rails. I'm learning rails by making something I would like to use.

I have an XML file, the contents of which I want to display to the user.

I've placed the XML file in the assets folder. But I have no idea what to do next. I've read loads of tutorials that say to use Nokogiri or REXML but what they don't say is where to put any of the commands.

My question is what's better to use and where do I put everything?

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri is more popular. Probably a better choice in my opinion because it will be better
documented. You can put your XML file anywhere you want. You could put it in `lib/` or `public/`
for example.

It doesn't really matter where, because Rails isn't going to be autoloading it.

You're going to need to give the filename anyway when you load it up.

So say it's in `lib/`, you can write `my_xml = File.read(Rails.root.join("lib", "my_file.xml")`

Then you load it into Nokogiri with `xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(my_xml)`. You can write your Nokogiri
code pretty much anywhere as well. Use it in a model, or a controller, or as a new file in
`config/initializers` (because files here are auto-loaded).

Then read [Nokogiri tutorials](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/) for more info.